# how can i access to <TextInput> in class foo in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I set `test` as an `id` for `<TextInput>` and then i added below code to `class  foo` to turn the `focus` to `True`:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.test, "focus", True))
```

But when i run the program it shows me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'test'
```

I think i can not access to `<TextInput>` with using `self.test` because it is in a different class.

I tried to use this:

```
class TextInput():
    pass
tt=TextInput()
```

and then :

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(tt, "focus", True))
```

But it got complicated and did not work.

How can i access to `<TextInput>` in `class foo(App)`?

Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.app import runTouchApp 
from kivy.clock import Clock 

Builder.load_string("""

<Button>
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 33
    width: 100
    text:'1'
    background_normal: ''
    background_down:'1, .3, .4, .85'
    background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
  



<TextInput>
    id:test
    selection_color:1, .3, .4, .4
    on_text_validate:app.enter()
    cursor_color: 255/255, 223/255, 5/255, 1
    multiline:False
    height: 33
    width:800
    size_hint: (None, None)
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    foreground_color: 255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8


    
<Grid>
    
    t1:t1
    b1:b1
    grid:grid
    grid2:grid2

  
    
    GridLayout:

      
        cols:1
        id:grid
        size: root.width  ,root.height 
        
        
        ScrollView:
             
            id:scroll
            bar_height:333
            bar_margin:3
            size_hint: 1,1
            bar_width: 15
            bar_color: 255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8 
            bar_inactive_color:255/255, 143/255, 5/255, 0.8 
            do_scroll_x:False
            do_scroll_y:True
            bar_pos_y:'right'
            scroll_type:['bars','content']
            
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:192/255,192/255,192/255,.3
                RoundedRectangle:
                    radius:[10] 
                    size:15 ,root.height 
                    pos:root.width - scroll.bar_width - scroll.bar_margin,0

            
            
            GridLayout:
                height: 5000
                size_hint:1,None
                spacing:6
                id:grid2
                cols:2
                 
            
                Button:
                    id:b1
     
                TextInput:
                    id:t1
                     
                 

""")

c=[1]



class Grid(Widget):
 
    def enter(self):
              c.append(1)
              self.grid2.add_widget(Button(text='%s'%len(c)))
              self.grid2.add_widget(TextInput())
               
               

gr=Grid() 
class foo(App):

    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor='#1618388'
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.test, "focus", True))   
        return gr
    def enter(self):
        gr.enter()
     





if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the `AttributeError` is that your `root` widget has no attr. 'test' (that you want to access as an id). The `id` you've assigned to that `TextInput` instance is 't1' not 'test'. You have to access that id (or instance according to your design) from the app's `root` once that is defined.

The correct way and order to achieve that can be like this,

```py
    def build(self):
        # First declare the `root`.
        self.root = gr
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.root.ids.t1, "focus", True))
        # The following will also work according to your design.
        # Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: setattr(self.root.t1, "focus", True))
        return self.root
```

Comment: I am using 

`self.grid2.add_widget(TextInput())`

to add new `TextInput`s and i can not use `t1` instead of  `TextInput()` because i already added that to my GridLayout.
So if i use `Clock.schedule_once` for `t1`  after pressing enter the new `TextInput` will not have `focus:True` .
And the reason for using clock is because if i use `focus:True` directly in kv language it will not work.

Comment: I can't follow you. The above code tried to answer the following : *'How can i access to <TextInput> in class...'*.